# Writing testable code with Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

The signature for `DeviceClient` class in `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` is

`public sealed class DeviceClient : IDisposable`.

This doesn't really suggest ideas for how to write testable code for the class that uses the client.

The client depends on a transport layer which sounds promising ("let's provide the transport and then mock it in tests; something like `HttpClient` and `HttpMessageHandler`") but the factory methods `DeviceClient.Create` take the transport as an `enum` so this angle of attack seem to be closed.

Is an adapter pattern (i.e. re-implement the interface) the way to go?

Answer (score 3):

With a sealed class and no virtual methods, an interface and adapter pattern may be the best (though high maintenance) solution.   You need interception and so have you looked at Microsoft Fake framework [and use a shim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx) to isolate that assembly when testing.